# cocoa:  resize split view subview size

Tags: cocoa

I want to hide a subview after I click a button, for example.

[image]

after I click hide button, the application should hide the NSTabView,(Not NSTableView!!!). but the problem is the NSTableView at top didn't resize, as follow:
[image]

How to make NSTableView auto resize to fill the blank after I hide the NSTabView?

My code about hiding the bottom subView:

```
 NSRect frame = [self.customView frame];
frame.size = NSMakeSize(0, 0);
[[self.customView  animator] setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Are these 2 view embedded in an NSSplitView as your title suggests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code for the hide button, just include code that increases the frame size of your scroll view (that contains the table view).